# How to do wav-> mp3 and then mp3-> wav in a piplined fashion in python

Tags: python, compression, mp3

As far as I know, it is possible to compress a wav file and then exported it to a mp3 file or uncompress a mp3 file and then export it to a wav file using **pydub**. I'd like to do compression and uncompression in a piplined fashion without reading from or writing to a file, instead directly from or to memory like this, mp3 = encode(wav, bitrate) and then wav' = decode(mp3) repeatedly. Can someone please explain to me how to do this with **pydub** or other libraries? Thanks!

Comment: What does "compress" mean? Are you zipping the files?

Comment: I meant mp3 compression/uncompression when I said "compress/uncompress".

Comment: Here is an example of using pydub to compress wav to mp3, but I'd like to
pass a wav (or mp3) array to pydub and get a mp3 (or wav) array from
pydub without reading from or writing to a file so that I can process
audio in a piplined fashion.

import pydub
sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav("D:/example/apple.wav")
sound.export("D:/example/apple.mp3", format="mp3")